# C++ container allowing access to rows and columns

Tags: c++, class, matrix

Is there an implementation of a simple container in which it would be possible to access whole dimensions from a matrix (it will have equal amount of numbers as columns)?

I know there is no standard implementation, but someone must have cooked up something?

So instead of only being able to access one dimension as a whole:

```
matrix[0]; // 1 2 3 4
matrix[1]; // 1 2 3 4
matrix[0][0] // 1
```

What I would like to be able to do:

```
matrix[ALL][0]; // 1 1
matrix[ALL][1]; // 2 2
```

Clarification:

In R using matrix[ , 1] and matrix[1, ] allow access to both dimensions, in Python: matrix[ :, 1] and matrix[1, :].

Comment: What data type you assume your "matrix[ALL][0]" should be?

Comment: `valarray` and `slice` might help.

Comment: The closest construct might be a `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie `int[2]` with `{1,1}` as content?

Comment: I *think* I understand the end-goal, but could you clarify what the significance of `ALL` is with a more concrete example? (I might just be slow off the draw this morning). Is it the *columns* you want access to ?

Comment: I assume the type to be user definable.

Comment: This is what `std::valarray` was designed for, but I don't know how efficient its implementation in today's major compilers is.

Answer (score 0):

Use vector of vectors:

```
vector< vector<int> > vec;
```

You access column like:

```
vec(1)
```

and individual elements like:

```
vec(1)(1)
```

Comment: actually, you would use `operator[](size_t n)` in both cases (`vex[1][1]`), but I don't think the OP is asking how to do this. Maybe he/she is, but ....

Comment: And vector of vectors is usually not a particularly good implementation for this sort of thing.

Comment: The question is indeed to select `vec("all elements here")(1)`